# Appending to URL end with JS request on form change

Tags: javascript, html, get

My code is as follows:

```
<h1>Sort by</h1>
<form>
<select name='myfield' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
<option value="Relevance">Relevance</option>
<option value="Date">Date Posted</option>
</select>
<noscript><input type="submit" value="Submit"></noscript>
</form>
```

Whenever I change the form and it auto-submits, a new field "myfield" is added to URL end. How can I get the URL to remain the same, and add "myfield" query just to the end of the URL, not deleting the existing URL query strings?

Comment: Do you want to send it as a URL param? can't u use post request?

Comment: I wish to send it as a URL param so the user can bookmark it.

Answer (score 0):

Store the URL parameter values in a hidden field with the same name
ex:

URL: `http://localhost/test.php?myfield1=x`

```
<h1>Sort by</h1>
<form>
    <input type='hidden' name='myfield1' value='<?php echo $_GET['myfield1']; ?>' />   


<select name='myfield' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
<option value="Relevance">Relevance</option>
<option value="Date">Date Posted</option>
</select>
<noscript><input type="submit" value="Submit"></noscript>
</form>
```